# If $\tan^2\theta=1-e^2$, then the value of $\sec\theta+\tan^3\theta \csc \theta$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $\tan^2\theta = 1-e^2$,then the value of
>   $\sec\theta$ + $\tan^3\theta \cdot \csc\theta$ is...

NOTE:
$1/\cos\theta +\cos^3\theta/\sin^3\theta \cdot 1/\sin\theta$

multiply: $\sin^2 \theta/\cos \theta$ then we get

$\sin^2\theta/\cos^2\theta+\cos\theta \cdot 1/\tan\theta \cdot \tan\theta$

so $1-e^2 + \cos\theta$.

Comment: I cleaned up the TeX in the title, maybe you could do the same for the body.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\sec\theta+\tan^3\theta\csc\theta
&=\frac1{\cos\theta}+\tan^2\theta\cdot\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\cdot\frac1{\sin\theta} \\
&=\frac1{\cos\theta}\left(1+\tan^2\theta\right) \\
&=\sec\theta\sec^2\theta
\end{align*}

Now $\sec^2\theta=1+\tan^2\theta=1+1-e^2$.

Comment: something went wrong @lab bhattacharjee.

Comment: @jyothika, Why do you think so?

Comment: see in last step.sec theta.sec^2 theta  ,sec^2 theta=1+ tan^2 theta,sec thlabbhattacharjeeeta= sqrt(1+tan^2 theta) so sqrt(1+tan^2theta)*(1+1-e^2)

Comment: @jyothika, the answer will be $$(\pm\sqrt{2-e^2})^3=\pm(2-e^2)^{\frac32}$$

Comment: $ \sqrt\(1+1-e^2)*(1+1-e^2)$

Comment: @jyothika, You mean $$\sec\theta(1+\tan^2\theta)=\pm\sqrt{2-e^2}\cdot(2-e^2)$$ which is same as $$\pm(1-e^2)^{1+\frac12}=\cdots$$

Comment: (1+1-e^2)^1/2*(1+1-e^2)

Comment: yes same @lab bhattacharjee.now you are correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16825/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-jyothika).

Comment: I believe @jyothika was confused because you wrote a + sign where you meant an = sign.  I have corrected the mistake and everything should be fine now (no need for a second edit, jyothika).

Comment: I couldn't able to chat with you @lab bhattacharjee.I was there but i didnt find the message box to type.If i login it shows a different page.